# AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:options: blocks main thread with remote URL?

Tags: ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, avurlasset

I've found no documentation about this, but in my practical experience

```
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
```

(where url is a remote URL for an HLS live stream), will block the main thread if the network is down or for some reason the file cannot be read.

**Has anyone else noticed this?** I may end up changing my setup to use GCD to construct on a background thread. Because as it is the UI locks up any time videos can't be loaded.

The `AVPlayerItem` loads things asynchronously, but `AVURLAsset` does not seem to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Had this issue too. Solved it with the following:

```
let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url)

// I'm using a resource loader for my custom urls...
let loaderQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "loader-queue", qos: .userInteractive)
asset.resourceLoader.setDelegate(self, queue: self.loaderQueue)

// load values asynchronously and once complete, create the player item
let keys = ["duration", "tracks"]
asset.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: keys, completionHandler: {
    let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
    self.player.insert(item, after: nil)
})
```

Comment: Hey Ed, what if my URLs aren't custom? For example link for Instagram?